# Most forward way to convert an angular web project to a mobile app

Tags: angular, mobile, web-applications, ionic2, angular2-nativescript

I was thinking about learning nativescript, when I realized that you need to do a lot of things differently to achieve what you want. I don't like that proprietary stuff. I don't wanna write an app in "2 separate languages/main frameworks".

Which framework would you recommend to convert a web project to a mobile "application"? At the moment, Ionic seems to be the best way to achieve that, if a custom layout isn't considered evil.

Comment: Why do I get closing votes? Is anything wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic is a good choice because it is here for the longest time.

Alternatively, you can take a look at:

https://mobile.angular.io/

This is in alpha state for now, but it is promising since it is Angular.io product

Comment: Wow man... that sounds very promising! I'll see if there are some other opinions, but atm I feel very appealed by that native-mobile approach.

Comment: Yep. They are talking about it for some time. Progressive apps are one of their main focus now with angular.

Comment: Some people complain that the project is over a year old and it still has the most basic issues. It seems that this isn't a big focus of angular. Even the official "Getting Started" is not possible. The `--mobile` parameter doesn't work at all and it seems that this is an issue existing since a longer time and you only find it over the github-issues section.

Comment: It seems that they aren't investing so much resources to develop this project. Is it because of Ionic doing light speed? Not sure. But a lot of articles are talking that there are some not anticipated problems on mobile devices.